# Angular FormGroup.AddControl causing form to submit

Tags: angular, formgroups

I'm working on an Angular form that looks something like this:

```js
form = new FormGroup({});
itemCount = 0

addItem(value?: string) {
  const newFormControl = new FormControl({
      value: value || '',
      disabled: value ? false : true
    });
    
    this.form.addControl(`item.${this.itemCount}`, newFormControl);
    this.items.push({/* item goes here*/})
    this.brandCount++;
}
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" class="full-width">
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addNewItem()">
    Add Item
   </button>
   // a div with an #ngFor directive to loop over the items array
   // and has some basic markup
   <button type="button" mat-icon-button 
    (click)="deleteItem($event, i)">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm having is that the call to this.form.addControl is causing the onSubmit function to be called. There are other components in the app where this isn't happening, and so far the only difference I can see is that the "Add Items" button is no inside the form. Does that make a difference, or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default 'form' treats all button as submit button for some reason.
You forgot to add `type="button"` in add item button.

Fixing this will work.

```js
form = new FormGroup({});
itemCount = 0

addItem(value?: string) {
  const newFormControl = new FormControl({
      value: value || '',
      disabled: value ? false : true
    });
    
    this.form.addControl(`item.${this.itemCount}`, newFormControl);
    this.items.push({/* item goes here*/})
    this.brandCount++;
}
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" class="full-width">
  <button mat-button type="button" color="primary" (click)="addNewItem()">
    Add Item
   </button>
   // a div with an #ngFor directive to loop over the items array
   // and has some basic markup
   <button type="button" mat-icon-button 
    (click)="deleteItem($event, i)">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thought it was in there, thanks for the extra pair of eyes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your  declaration in html to div. It will work.

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="full-width">
    <button (click)="addItem()">
      Add Item
    </button>
    // a div with an #ngFor directive to loop over the items array
    // and has some basic markup
    <button type="button"   (click)="deleteItem($event, i)">
        delete
    </button>
    <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">
        submit
    </button>
</div>
```